# Android Multiple RTSP video streams

Tags: android

I want to make an Android app which should be capable of playing at least 6 Live RTSP video streams with functionality of pause and play. Is there any way to achieve this efficiently. Thanks in advance.
[Android Video Streaming Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFwFq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I never used it but there is a library for stream in rtmp and rtsp. Here is the github : https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java